Is there a simple API method of getting URLs to GitHub releases of a repository?
I'm trying to write a mirror for a GitHub repository, and want to know if there is a Simple API version of the tags/releases page such as the Simple API version of PyPI (https://pypi.org/simple/{package_name}).
In PyPI's case, all of the publicly available versions of a package are listed on a single page, allowing for easy URL identification and forwarding. At present, I have only been able to find the tags page for a repository (https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/tags), which provides only the latest 10 versions per page, and which you have to go into in order to identify the specific file URLs for that particular release. This makes trawling the site for all versions of that package non-trivial.
Is there a similar option for GitHub, where all the files associated with public version releases of a particular repository are displayed on a single web page? Thanks!

I suggest that Googling for "github api repository releases" will be a fruitful exercise.

Found it, thanks!

For people stumbling across this in the future:
Yes, GitHub does have API endpoints that can be poked in order to acquire information regarding releases from. The URL takes the format https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo_name}/releases (E.g., GitHub's CodeQL Action can be found at https://api.github.com/repos/github/codeql-action/releases)
Querying the URL will return a response containing a list of JSON objects, with each JSON object containing information and download links related to a specific version release.
Official documentation on how to interact with the GitHub REST API can be found here:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/getting-started-with-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28
